# How to make Gmail obey `X-SES-Spam-Verdict`

Tags: gmail, amazon-web-services, spam-prevention, aws-ses

I recently transferred a domain to AWS SES and now most users are getting spam in their inbox (false negatives), even though SES spam filtering *correctly* flags all such spam with the header `X-SES-Spam-Verdict: FAILURE`.

All users are using Gmail, myself included - but I can not find a way to create a Gmail filter that could match headers.

Alternate solution would be to make SES forward the mail to `username+SPAM@gmail.com`, but I'd rather not start hacking the [lambda script](https://github.com/arithmetric/aws-lambda-ses-forwarder)

Comment: OK, since so many of you seem to think that this is off-topic, can you please suggest on which stackexhange site should I ask this, then?

Comment: Web Apps would be a better fit.  People probably haven't commented because this will likely be migrated for you with a few more votes.